# How do I make a function with an array output?

Tags: python, arrays

Let X be an array of shape (100,200,3)

When a 3-dimensional vector y is given, I want to define a function f such that f(y) is an array of shape (100,200) such that f(y)[i][j] is the l2 distance between X[i][j] and y.

Here is how I tried:

```
import numpy as np
def norm(n):
    return np.linalg.norm(n)

def sdistance(y,i,j):
    return norm(np.asarray(y)-X[i][j]

def distance(y):
    return ???
```

I want to define the last function distance(y) so that distance(y) is an array of shape (100,200) such that distance(y)[i][j]=sdistance(y,i,j).

How do I properly define the function distance(y)?

Comment: Sounds like a job for reshaping and [`pdist`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.pdist.html#scipy.spatial.distance.pdist).

Comment: What's the reason for downvoting my post? Maybe my question sounds very stupid, but I am completely new to this subject..

Comment: @user11 probably because you haven't really "tried" anything... `return ???` doesn't show much effort...

Answer (score 0):

If we literally translate your description to code it would look something like follows:

```
import numpy as np

X = np.random.random((100,200,3))

def norm(n):
    return np.linalg.norm(n)

def sdistance(y,i,j):
    return norm(np.asarray(y)-X[i,j])

def distance(y):
    return np.linalg.norm(X - y,axis=2)
```

The last function should be equivalent to the following which follows your description more literally.

```
def distance(y):
    output = np.zeros(X.shape[0:2])
    for i in range(X.shape[0]):
        for j in range(X.shape[1]):
            output[i,j] = sdistance(y,i,j)
    return output
```